# Show EXE file path of running processes on the command-line in Windows

Tags: windows

How can I show the full EXE file path of each running process from the command-line in Windows?

I've tried [tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730909.aspx) and [pslist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx), but they don't show the full path:

```
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq Spring.Tests.exe" /v /fo List
```

Gives:

```
Image Name:   Spring.Tests.exe
PID:          3956
Session Name: Console
Session#:     1
Mem Usage:    9,772 K
Status:       Running
User Name:    W81ENTX64DELPHI\Developer
CPU Time:     0:00:01
Window Title: Spring
```

and

```
pslist Spring.Tests -x
```

gives:

```
Name                Pid      VM      WS    Priv Priv Pk   Faults   NonP Page
Spring.Tests       3956   83472    9772    5320    5692     5037     11  157
 Tid Pri    Cswtch            State     User Time   Kernel Time   Elapsed Time
1488  10     11018     Wait:UserReq  0:00:00.906   0:00:01.046    0:53:06.977
```

Since `Spring.Tests.exe` can be in various directories, I want to know which one was executed.

Comment: oh that's a classic question.. besides task manager having a column. For command line, WMIC and powershell can. it's even on here or on stackoverflow.. must be all over the place... Actually I can't see it fully answered on here, i have a note of it.. i'll check

Comment: @barlop it's funny: while you wrote your comment, I was already experimenting with PowerShell, as I'd been doing some [other PowerShell experimenting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218482/whats-the-maximum-number-of-columns-for-format-table-cmdlet-in-powershell?noredirect=1#comment37399115_24218482) as well (:

Comment: no need for a ':(' your method is very neat and you found it fast

Comment: Note the (: is a reverse one, so I was (and still am!) happy.

Comment: I must be autistic! Maybe you should put a nose in the smiley to make it clearer ;-)

Comment: None of the answers for this question are reliable. I'm using an external tool and trying to check running versions installed versus a potentially new version, and I've found absolutely nothing to reliably get this info in a general sense. Many answers will work for many EXEs, but not all of them. You can query the process/service, but it doesn't guarantee that a populated Path field will be returned.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck I have better success running the solutions under an elevated UAC token, but really wish there was a command-line version of https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx that allows reliable querying under that token.

Comment: Seriously, @JeroenWiertPluimers... that would be _great_

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to the rescue.

First I used [Get-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176854.aspx) to see what [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) could return:

```
PowerShell Get-Process ^| Get-Member
```

Then I [filtered the Path from Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx) to figure out which `Spring.Tests` processes were running:

```
PowerShell Get-Process Spring.Tests ^| Format-List Path
```

resulting in:

```
Path : C:\Users\Developer\Versioned\Spring4D\Tests\Bin\DelphiXE\Spring.Tests.exe
```

which is exactly the information I wanted.

Comment: there is WMIC too but powershell is more modern and flexible

Comment: Is `Path` the same thing as command line? What about the *arguments* to the executable? @barlop WMI still has a number of features that are otherwise unavailable in PowerShell.

Comment: @jpmc26 I didn't need those, but I think you can get them via `StartInfo` instead of `Path` based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012409/system-diagnostics-process-arguments

Comment: @jpmc26  the file paths that the wmic command outputs, are the same as the file paths that the powershell ........ command there outputs  e.g. open windows calculator and try it for calc.exe https://pastebin.com/raw/TK8xSPPL

Comment: What does the carrot do in the first command?

Comment: @JaredBeach it's the `cmd.exe` escape character; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342828/what-does-symbol-means-in-batch-script In this case, it ensures that the pipe is for `PowerShell`, not `cmd`.

Answer (score 45):

In addition to the line you gave, here are a bunch of lines that (apart from the second one) can be used to list paths:

```
PS C:\> gwmi win32_process | select Handle, CommandLine | format-list
PS C:\> gwmi win32_process | select name
PS C:\> gwmi win32_process | select CommandLine
C:\>wmic process get ProcessID,ExecutablePath
C:\>wmic process where "name='mysqld.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath
C:\>wmic process where "name='mysqld.exe'" get ProcessID, ExecutablePath /FORMAT:LIST
```

Comment: this has the advantage of being fast, (wmic) because powershell is so god darn slow!!!

Comment: Be very attentive to the formatting used. For example, not including the single-quote marks within the `name` field will cause this to break.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck well, given the length of the command i'd expect somebody to just copy/paste it anyway and just change the name of the process. So hopefully they shouldn't make the mistake of missing single quotes around the process name as they can leave the ones that are there.

Answer (score 13):

Pipe PowerShell's `Get-Process` into `Select-Object`.

Example command for Notepad++:

```
Get-Process notepad++ | Select-Object Path
```

Output:

```
Path
----
D:\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

Comment: To get output directly, `(Get-Process notepad++).Path` (maybe to store in a variable).

Comment: @nawfal I missed your comment back-then, but your solution is awesome! Running on `cmd.exe`, now `PowerShell (Get-Process procexp).Path` gives me `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sysinternals\tools\procexp.exe` without going through the `^|` redirect trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## In PowerShell:

General solution. To get path and other info of a process you would run:

> ```
> $ Get-Process <options> | Select-Object <options>
> ```

## For specific process PID you would run:

### Example:

```
Get-Process -Id 2728 | Select-Object -Property ProcessName, Id, WS, Path
```

### Outputs:

[image]

## For all processes with given name, you would run:

### Example:

```
Get-Process svchost | Select-Object -Property ProcessName, Id, WS, Path
```

### Outputs:

[image]

## Documentation:

[SelectObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2)

[Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: For me it showed the path when Powershell was run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I am running a file `abc.txt` and found the path by using this in the command line on Windows

```
wmic process where "CommandLine like '%abc.txt'" get commandline
```

You can try in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I found a command to show full path in windows, used like

```
where cmd.exe
```

`powershell`: is so slowly

`wmic`: many processes missing path information..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [`where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where) shows [`cmd.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) on the Windows search [`path`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/path), not where where `cmd.exe` is running from.

Example: on my system there is a difference on where `procexp.exe` is running from (`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sysinternals\tools\procexp.exe`) and where `procexp.exe` is on the `path` (`C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\procexp.exe`).